Error with "npm run serve" in a vue/cli project
When I create a new Vue project using "vue create project1", the project is created with the following errors, but it seems it creates it anyway:
/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/babel.config.js
0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL] /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/babel.config.js: Unexpected token '.' (While processing: "/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js")
/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/src/App.vue
0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL] /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/src/App.vue: Unexpected token '.' (While processing: "/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js")
/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL] /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/src/components/HelloWorld.vue: Unexpected token '.' (While processing: "/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js")
/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/src/main.js
0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL] /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/src/main.js: Unexpected token '.' (While processing: "/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js")
/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/vue.config.js
0:0  error  Parsing error: [BABEL] /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/vue.config.js: Unexpected token '.' (While processing: "/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proj2/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js")
However when I run "npm run serve" in the project, it throws the following (without having modified the project at all):

proyect1@0.1.0 serve
vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...
ERROR  Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the dependency tree.
Error: @vitejs/plugin-vue requires vue (>=3.2.13) or @vue/compiler-sfc to be present in the dependency tree.
at Object. (/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/compiler.js:14:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object. (/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js:29:20)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js:154:16
at /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:268:40
at Array.forEach ()
at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:268:26)
at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:272:48)
at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/PluginAPI.js:132:25)
at serve (/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:79:31)
at Service.run (/home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:262:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
I have checked the vue version with "npm list vue":
proyect1@0.1.0 /home/xxx/Documents/vue/proyect1
├─┬ @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8
│ └─┬ @vue/babel-preset-app@5.0.8
│   ├─┬ @vue/babel-preset-jsx@1.4.0
│   │ └── vue@3.4.27 deduped
│   └── vue@3.4.27 deduped
└─┬ vue@3.4.27
└─┬ @vue/server-renderer@3.4.27
└── vue@3.4.27 deduped
Have installed also compiler-sfc by hand but does not resolve de issue. In addition, I've tryed clearing the npm cache with npm cache clean --force, delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file in the project directory, and then run npm install, but did not have luck.
Does any one have ideas to try resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.
